# Convert byte[] to string like this "AAAAADT4RyQ="

Tags: c#, converters, encoder, decoder

There is byte array:
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 246, 141, 6 }

It somehow represented as a string:
AAAAADT4RyQ=

How to do it? What is the encoder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like base64 encoding to me:

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

That doesn't give *quite* the results you're expecting though - it gives `AAAAADT2jQY=`.

The base64 string you've given corresponds to  `{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 248, 71, 36 }` - without more information about where this data is coming from, or how you got the expected value, it's impossible to explain the discrepancy.